# SQL History Query

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to select data from a inventory history table. The main part of my query will pull:

```
select *
from inv_history
where updated_date between '2-sep-14' and '8-sep-14'
and inv_STATUS = 'ON HAND'
```

Then I also need to include the record of this data before the status went to 'ON HAND'. Any tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Introduce a `AFTER UPDATE` trigger when the `inv_status` changes to `ON HAND`

[This](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/triggers/after_update.php) link could help you.

Comment: The requirement is to fetch the rows satisfying the query predicate from the table now, not later stage when the trigger would make them available. And trigger is not always a good option, it is just a side effete of an action and not an action in itself.

Comment: @LalitKumarB: OP says "Then I also need to include the record of this data before the status went to 'ON HAND'" which I understand as having an audit before the status went into "ON HAND".

Answer (score 0):

`where updated_date between '2-sep-14' and '8-sep-14'`

Your query predicate is incorrect. You must need to apply `TO_DATE` to the date literals.

To answer your question regarding including the records before the status went to "ON HAND", add the following query to your query using `UNION ALL` :

`select *
from inv_history
where updated_date > ( select min(updated_date) from inv_history where between inv_STATUS = 'ON HAND')`

I would rather use `subquery factoring` to have the rows from inv_history as:

`with data as(
   Select * from inv_history
  where inv_status= 'ON_HAND'`

Use the above just once rather then accessing the inv_history twice.